# Regex in npp to find everything after and including a word until another word

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to generate a regex to catch anything (include newlines) after AS until SELECT to remove the AS.
There are multiple variations, and I want to repeat everytime there is an INSERT. Some don't have AS at all and should do nothing.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE schema.table1
AS
SELECT

INSERT OVERWRITE schema.table2
AS -- (some spaces sometimes here)
SELECT
```

I only want to remove Lines that start with AS, otherwise some other words might get changed.I can't figure out how to do a lazy regex that only does this, any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reged that you want:**     `AS[\d\D]*?(?=SELECT)`
[image]

You can look the demo here.
https://regex101.com/r/IFNqbG/3

Comment: thanks for the effort... unfortunately it needs to stop at the first select, and repeat again

Comment: @SpaceSteak, please let me know if I could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(INSERT\b.*?\R)AS.*?\R(?=SELECT\b)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(               : start group 1
  \bINSERT\b    : literally 'INSERT', with word boundaries to not match 'INSERTED' for instance
  .*?           : 0 or more anycharacter, not greedy
  \R            : any kind of linebreak
)               : end group 1
AS\b            : literally 'AS', with word boundary to not match 'ASSIGN' for instance
.*?             : 0 or more anycharacter, not greedy
\R              : any kind of linebreak
(?=SELECT\b)    : lookahead, make sure we have SELECT after but not SELECTED
```

- CHECK `. matches newline` if INSERT or AS lines can be on multiple lines

**Replacement:**

```
$1   : group 1
```

**Result for given example:**

```
INSERT OVERWRITE schema.table1
SELECT

INSERT OVERWRITE schema.table2
SELECT
```